# getting error in HTTPURLConnection while running program on linux server

Tags: java

I am running a progrom which is successfully running on my local machine(Success 200 Ok) but when I upload this to my linux web server I am getting the 404 error code.

My Code Is:

```
try{
String url = "http://sms.bazaardekho.com/ComposeSMS.aspx";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String username = "shaillu";
String priority="1";
String dnd="1";
String unicode="0";
String query = String.format("username=%s&priority=%s&dnd=%s&unicode=%s",
                       URLEncoder.encode(username, charset), 
                       URLEncoder.encode(priority, charset),
                       URLEncoder.encode(dnd, charset),
                       URLEncoder.encode(unicode, charset));
URL oracle = new URL(url + "?" + query);
HttpURLConnection yc =(HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();
yc.setRequestMethod("GET");
yc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
yc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "PARSHWA WEB SOLUTIONS");
yc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
out.println(yc.getRequestMethod());
out.println(yc.getResponseCode());
out.println(yc.getResponseMessage());
out.println("<br/>ErrorStream :"+yc.getErrorStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
}catch(Exception e){out.println("Exception:" + e);}
```

Output:

```
GET 404 Not Found 
ErrorStream :sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@33a719 Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://sms.bazaardekho.com/ComposeSMS.aspx?username=shaillu&priority=1&dnd=1&unicode=0
```

This program is successfully running on my local machine but when I am trying to run this on my online server to use for my website, then I am getting this error.
Please give me the cause of this error & how can I resolve this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You sure on your loal and presumably windows HttpURLConnection refers to thsi class only `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`

On linux its defaulting to the JDL provided class I beleive. A system wide property set smewhere or eclipse doing that for you :)

Comment: Yes on local machine HttpURLConnection refers to sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream. On server other links are running successfully but not getting that what error is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try changing this

```
yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "PARSHWA WEB SOLUTIONS");
```

to

```
yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
```